# найти пары атрибутов в таблице, у которых каждому значению одного атрибута соответствует одно значение другого атрибута

Tags: sql

Как с помощью sql - запроса, найти пары атрибутов в таблице, у которых каждому значению одного атрибута в любой момент времени соответствует одно значение другого атрибута?

Comment: Зачем это вам? Формулировки шибко напоминают определение первой нормальной формы, а в ней находятся все БД, к которым можно написать SQL-запрос.

Comment: нужно найти функциональные зависимости атрибутов от атрибутов составного ключа, чтобы привести ко 2 нормальной форме. Пишу программу на с# и хочу сформировать запрос к БД.

Comment: Вопрос поставлен некорректно. Если вы еще проектируете БД, то про SQL-запросы говорить рано. Елси вы рассчитываете, что вам дадут скрипт, который вы выполните, и ваша БД автоматически спроектируется  в 6 нормальной форме, то вы заблуждаетесь. Нужно усвоить теория, и использовать полученные знания при проектировании к БД. Почитайте хотя бы википедию, там большинство действий сопровождается примерами. "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Нормальная_форма#.D0.A2.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.8C.D1.8F_.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0_.283NF.29"

Comment: Вы должны на уровне логики понимать есть зависимость или ее нет. А жизнь вполне может подкинуть любую ситуацию и это не будет нарушением НФ. Например я добавляю в таблицу две записи у которых атрибут1 равен 5 и атрибут2 равен 10. при этом в таблице еще нет других записей с атрибут1 равен 5. Запрос выдаст вам что соответствие уникально, но это ничего не значит ибо завтра может появится запись 5-12. вопрос лишь в том, позволяет ваша модель хранить и 5-10 и 5-12 или нет и если нет - то почему

Answer (score 1):

Под "в любой момент времени" в формулировке нормальной формы (точнее, в формулировке термина *Функциональная зависимость*) подразумевается *любой момент* в настоящем, прошлом и *будущем*.

SQL оперирует данными, находящимися в базе данных в настоящий момент. С помощью SQL запроса нельзя определить, будет ли соблюдаться условие соответствия в будущем.

Это можно определить только анализом предметной области.